# Paypal Button works in sandbox not live

Tags: mysql, database, button, paypal

I have a paypal button that work perfectly in Sandbox. I can pay via paypal and have the information inserted into my database including some custom variables.

When I switch to live the user can pay and I recieve the payment but it will not update the database. The only thing thats changing is the paypal URL & email to reflect live values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I responded to this question at the PayPal forum where you posted the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was created by myself adding another field value to the button that did not have a unique value.